# Adding an extra column value with INSERT ... SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and my goal is to move specific data from the first table into the second table along with a reason for why that data was moved. For instance:

```
raw_data_table

SELECT * FROM raw_data_table where id IS NULL;
```

I would want to move this into the second table, which is identical to the first table except for an extra column `reason`. I tried:

```
INSERT INTO bad_data_table 
(SELECT * FROM raw_data_table WHERE id IS NULL), "The ID is NULL";
```

But this returns a syntax error. How can I copy the entire row over and add the reason value?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO bad_data_table 
SELECT *, 'The ID is NULL' AS Reason
FROM raw_data_table
WHERE id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I would look at breaking that `*` into column names as well. Otherwise, when someone ads a new column to the `Reason` table things will start blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO bad_data_table VALUES (
(SELECT * FROM raw_data_table WHERE id IS NULL LIMIT 1), "The ID is NULL");
```

The subquery here needs to have 1 row!

Comment: Error - `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) `