# Insert results of execute(@QueryString) into a table while adding an extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure that dynamically creates a SQL string, @SQLQuery. After I create this query, I need to execute the query and insert it into a table in the database while adding another column that specifies a unique ID for this particular insert. (Context: It is possible in this application that multiple groupings of data will be inserted into this table and I need to be able to differientiate between groupings at a later date. )

This issue is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584588/adding-an-extra-column-value-with-insert-select-in-mysql) except I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 instead of mysql. I have tried the solution there:

```
INSERT INTO data_table_name
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery), @SomeID
```

but MS SQL Server 2008 doesn't like that syntax.

Any ideas on how to do this in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store query result in table variable and then read from that with extra column and write to final table

```
DECLARE @temp table (col1 int, col2 varchar(10), ....)

INSERT INTO @temp
EXEC(@SQLQuery)

INSERT INTO data_table_name
SELECT *, @SomeID FROM @temp
```

You can also append @SomeID in your dynamic sql string.

Example:

```
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT *,' + @SomeID + ' FROM ' + @tableNameVar
```

and then do this

```
INSERT INTO data_table_name
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: I had an answer faster than I'm even allowed to accept an answer. Awesome. This works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you are doing this in a Stored Procedure, what I would suggest is for you to:

1. Execute the @SQLQuery first;
2. Upon successful execution of the @SQLQuery, insert the @SQLQuery to the table with the unique ID.

i.e.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @Param 

IF @@ERROR <> 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA(Query)
    VALUES(@SQLQuery)
  END
```

You're better off designing TableA such that the ID will be an Identity so that a unique sequential ID is generated when you insert a record into that table.

Comment: he wants single id value for set for values returned from query.