# Adding values to a column which is an result of a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I have a sample table:

```
xyz | abc | new_col

1   |  4    
2   |  4      
3   |  2  
4   |  1
```

I  run a query like

```
select count(*) as result from sample { A aggregate function which return true or false } ..
```

This gives me a result say:

```
result
-------
4
5
6
7
```

How can I add this result to column :new_col such that my table looks like:

```
xyz | abc | new_col

1   |  4   | 4 
2   |  4   | 5  
3   |  2   | 6
4   |  1   | 7
```

So basically I want the result output to be added to the new_col.

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584588/adding-an-extra-column-value-with-insert-select-in-mysql ?

Comment: Use `UPDATE`. How? Then you better explain your "aggregate function" and relation of new_col values to xyz|abc values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want then together then you

```
 SELECT xyz , abc , count(*) as result from sample 
                   WHERE (ur condition) group by xyz,abc
```

If you want them together then select them together. Btw what do you mean by { A aggregate function which return true or false }. IF u have issue with that then white the function so that we see.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Sample_table 
select count(*) as result from sample { A aggregate function which return true or false } ..
WHERE new_col IS NULL;
```